# Алгоритм разбора УРЛа

Tags: php, javascript, c++, алгоритм, url

Существует ли универсальный алгоритм разбора УРЛа?

Должен, как я понимаю, разбирать следующее:

1. name1=value1&name2=value2
2. param1/param2/param3
3. param1/param2/name1=value1&name2=value2

Comment: Вы одновременно пишете разбор URL'a на PHP, JS и C++?

Comment: Нет... Мне не важен язык программирования, важен сам алгоритм... Можно на любом из перечисленных языков

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пришлось самому написать:

```
    string path = "param1/param2/name1=value1&name2=value2";

pos = 0;
int posEnd = path.length();
int mode = 1;
int index = 1;
string name = "", value = "";

while (true) {
    if (pos >= posEnd || path[pos] == '/' || path[pos] == '&') {
        if (mode == 1) {
            if (name != "") {
                value = name;
                name = "p" + to_string(index);
                index++;
                params.insert(name, value);
                name = "";
                value = "";
            }
        }
        else {
            params.insert(name, value);
            name = "";
            value = "";
            mode = 1;
        }
        if (pos >= posEnd) break;
    }
    else if (path[pos] == '=') {
        mode = 2;
    }
    else {
        if (mode == 1) name += path[pos]; else value += path[pos];
    }
    pos++;
}
```

Comment: Не совсем правильно. Вы разбираете очень специальный случай URI. В [RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986) приводятся, например, такие варианты: `ftp://ftp.is.co.za/rfc/rfc1808.txt`, `mailto:John.Doe@example.com`, `tel:+1-816-555-1212`. Всё это URI. А у вас по сути разбор query string (но вы забыли декодировать  значения параметров) и segments.

Comment: Структура URL: <схема>://<логин>:<пароль>@<хост>:<порт>/<URL‐путь>?<параметры>#<якорь> ... мне нужен был разбор этого: <URL‐путь>?<параметры>

Comment: ... в предположении, что он делится слешем на части. Так часто бывает, но это вовсе не обязательно. Кроме того, и синтаксис query не настолько жёсткий, там может быть в принципе что угодно. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Generic_syntax

Answer (score 3):

*url* (*uniform resource locator*) — это часть *uri* (*uniform resource identifier*).

[разбор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI#.D0.A0.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.B1.D0.BE.D1.80_.D1.81.D1.82.D1.80.D1.83.D0.BA.D1.82.D1.83.D1.80.D1.8B_URI) структуры *uri*.

[rfc3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), описывающий структуру *uri*.

Comment: http://www.ics.uci.edu/pub/ietf/uri/#Related
дадут следующие результаты соответственно:

http:
http
//www.ics.uci.edu
www.ics.uci.edu
/pub/ietf/uri/
нет результата
нет результата
#Related
Related .... а мне главное разобрать вот это "/pub/ietf/uri/", ну и как описано в вопросе

Comment: так возьмите только нужную часть от регулярного выражения.

Comment: И сможет разобрать, то что указано в вопросе?

Comment: проверить, мне кажется, несложно.

Comment: не получилось... как-то слишком сложно всё это